# In what units are glVertex arguments measured in?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

So i recently started learning JOGL after being bored if Vanillla Java since no ideas came to my mind. I have learned how to draw triangles, lines and everything simple but theres what i do not understand. What are opengl measurement units because it clearly doesnt count pixels by default. 
My render method:

```
private void render(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_LINES);
    gl.glVertex3f( 0.25f, -0.25f, 0);
    gl.glVertex3f(-0.25f,  0.25f, 0);
    gl.glEnd(); }
```

Even a dumb person would undestand that to render out a line which is 0.25 pixels wide is impossible. So what's the catch here? :)
Looking forward to your answer!
Best regards!

Comment: I'm not sure if there any units, but...  The default screen coordinates are `1.0` to `-1.0` AFAIK.. However, you're not limited to using only those coordinates (which are quite hard to use when dealing with stuff like 0.0032 etc.), so to make it more easier, you can change the view model matrix to your liking to extend that.

Comment: Those *default screen coordinates* are wrong. Again, you can set them to whatever you want. If you set your screen dimensions to `-1.0` - `1.0` then `0.0` will be at the middle of the screen. Many programs set the screen dimensions to match pixels so `1.0` GL unit *really is* 1 pixel.

Comment: Good question by the way.

Comment: The units are known as object-space, and they are quite meaningless without transforming into a well-defined coordinate space such as view- (after modelling and viewing transform) or clip-space (after projection).

Comment: @Qix Those coordinates are actually valid, because `glVertex3f (...)` sets the W coordinate to a constant **1.0**. Given identity matrices for ModelView and Projection, that means object-space is the same thing as clip-space. Provided the constant W coordinate of **1.0** the equivalence can be taken one step farther and we can say that the vertex position is in NDC space.

Comment: @Qix The caveat is that the [**-1.0**,**1.0**] coordinate range applies to the corners of the viewport (defined in window coordinates). So without the viewport mapping, there is no way to make any relationship between projection and pixel scale.

Comment: "Wrong" was the wrong word; I meant the statement `The default screen coordinates` isn't necessarily correct. You are correct.

Comment: Thank you all! I can understand now a bit more :) Great people, great website!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Whatever you want them to be](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/quick-question-about-opengl-%27units%27-209629/#post1069876).

OpenGL doesn't have any idea of scale, per se. In fact, most 3D engines don't care. It's all perspective.

If your tower is 3x the height of your player, your player's GL height could be `1.0`, `5.0`, or `0.1`. That just means your tower height is going to be `3.0`, `15.0`, or `0.3` respectively.

[Minecraft](http://minecraft.net), for example, defines one block as `1.0` in OpenGL units; which, in the 'lore', equates to 1 meter in-game. Everything has been scaled to fit that model.

Comment: Understood, but can i change the units to pixels or to something similar? I hope i don't ask too many stupid questions :) Also thank you alot for your answer!

Comment: Sure; just set the viewport size to the screen size in pixels. Then your units will effectively be scaled to 1 pixel per 1 GL unit.

Comment: @Qix Setting the viewport only sets where OpenGL renders; it doesn't affect the coordinates. To render pixels, set up an orthographic projection matrix from (0,0) to (screenw, screenh).

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo `s/viewport size/projection matrix/` :) You're right.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo It affects the scale and offset of the projected image, however; thus it ***does*** affect how object-space coordinates are transformed to window-space. To do this properly (have object-space coordinates match pixel scale) you basically need the perfect combination of projection matrix and matching viewport. It is easy to forget the second part since GL automatically sizes the viewport to the window dimensions when you create your framebuffer.